# Where to find ARM GCC compiler in XCODE5?

Tags: xcode, development, gcc

I am trying to run kivy on Mac and it relies on my Xcode arm gcc compiler.

I already tryied to answer this question in a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922885/how-to-find-arm-apple-darwin-llvm-gcc-4-2-compiler-on-xcode-5) but here I we again...

Where to find the **arm apple llvm gcc** compiler in the new XCode 5?

Comment: In case my pointing out the gcc that ships with Xcode isn't what you seek, what is it that you are really trying to do?

Comment: The thing is: XCode 4.x used to come with the LLVM GCC compiler. BUT Xcode5 does not contain it, according to the [Apple website](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_0.html). So how to install or point to a gcc compiler (in my case, one that compiles for ARM platform)?? I alrady added this issue to the [kivy ios github page](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios/issues/62)

Answer (score 2):

Apple stopped shipping gcc with Xcode.

The clang compiler presents itself as gcc (technically I believe it's an llvm front end that respects many gcc flags) when you install Xcode from the Mac App Store:

```
Mac:~ me$ xcrun --find gcc
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
Mac:~ me$ `xcrun --find gcc` --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

If you need a different compiler, you'll likely need to download it elsewhere or build it from source.

Comment: But does it compile for ARM platform or only for x86_64?

Comment: As far as this site goes - that's the compiler with Xcode and we don't get into code level details. Also, kivy should ship with everything you need - http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-macosx.html